# Civilization V Keyboard shortcuts missing in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I used a couple of very useful keyboard shortcuts in Civ 5 that don't appear to exist in Civ 6.

`C` to centre the map on the selected unit is extremely useful if the map is somewhere else for some reason.

`W` to make a unit wait so you can come back to it before the end of your turn is also very useful.

Are there any alternative shortcuts for these (nothing in Settings)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this in-game.
However, much of the code isn't hidden, but is in easily modifiable .lua files, specifically WorldInput.lua.

https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/58q3qj/psa_guide_on_how_to_enable_wasd_andor_other/

This link contains several examples of how to add new hotkeys.  For example the code snippet

```
if (uiKey == Keys.YOUR_KEY_HERE) then
    local unit:table = UI.GetHeadSelectedUnit();
    if unit ~= nil then
        UI.LookAtPlot( unit:GetX(), unit:GetY() );
    end
end
```

can be used to make the 'C' key center the view on the current unit, and

```
if (uiKey == Keys.W) then
    UI.SelectNextReadyUnit();
end
```

to cycle units.

In the end, the range of new hotkeys is determined by the functions accessible, and I don't see a list of functions yet.  Luckily for you, there's already examples of what you want to add.